# Where can i see user profiles?

Tags: loadout

I would like to see stats from other users.

So far i did not find any userprofiles except my own (ingame).

Where can i see stats for other users/their user profile?

I did not find any on their site either.

Answer (score -4):

It can't be done, I have also searched everywhere!
Maybe suggest putting in that feature on their forum.